# Why isn't my cell data showing up in UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My Cells are populated accurately!  How is this not loading into tableview??

How is my data not showing up?  How is this possible?

My return cells are printing out just as they need be - what pushes them up onto the table?

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import MapKit
//import CoreLocation

class ToolTableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

//    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var jsonArray:NSMutableArray?
    var tools = [Tool]()

    @IBOutlet weak var toolListSearchBar: UISearchBar!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLat: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
    var currentLong: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
//        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
        currentLat = location.coordinate.latitude
        currentLong = location.coordinate.longitude
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        self.tableView.registerClass(ToolTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ToolTableViewCell")
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }
        else{
            print("Location service disabled");
        }

    }


    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
        tools = []

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let userid: Int = defaults.objectForKey("toolBeltUserID") as! Int

        let searchTerm = String(toolListSearchBar.text!)
        print(searchTerm)


        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:3000/tools/search", parameters: ["keyword": searchTerm, "latitude": currentLat, "longitude": currentLong,
            "user": userid]) .responseJSON {response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("\(JSON)")

               for i in 0 ..< JSON.count {

                let owner = JSON[i].objectForKey("owner")
                let tool = JSON[i].objectForKey("tool")
                let title = tool!["title"] as! String!
                let ownerId = owner!["id"] as! Int!
                let distanceToTool = JSON[i].objectForKey("distance") as! Double
                var description: String

                    if let des = tool!["description"] as?  NSNull {
                        description = ""
                    } else {
                        description = (tool!["description"] as? String!)!
                    }

                    let myTool = Tool(title: title!, description: description, ownerId: ownerId!, distance: distanceToTool)


                    self.tools.append(myTool)

                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                })

            } else {
                print("Sent search term, but no response")
            }
        }

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(tools.count)
        return tools.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "ToolTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ToolTableViewCell
        let tool = tools[indexPath.row]

        cell.title?.text = tool.title
//       print(tool.title)
//        cell.toolListDescription?.text = tool.description
        cell.ownerId = tool.ownerId
//        print(tool.ownerId)
//       print(tool.distance)
//        cell.distance?.text = "\(tool.distance)mi"

        print(cell)
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the logs please

Comment: I see you are actually subclassing UITableViewController.  I'm more accustomed to simply having my view controller implement the UITableVewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols.  I'm not saying "right or wrong" here, but maybe there's some kind of "gotcha" when subclassing?

Comment: ^ ive actually just started thinking about this. This issue is way too bizarro to be holding me up like this and i think it might have something to do with this. I'm gonna try to rebuild the class structure and see if that helps. Thanks1

Comment: can it be because you're receiving the data after populating the tableview? A good way to verify that is to create a simple button with a `tableview.reloadData()` and press it 5 seconds after opening the view. If it fills the tableview means that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    }
```

you may add this code ?

```
if let cell = nil {
    cell = you cell init?
}
```

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always returns a reusable cell instance but nil

Comment: But nil? Im not sure what that means?